# Play2 - "src_managed" and "classes_managed" directories not created by activator

Tags: playframework, sbt, typesafe-activator

I work on a playframework projet, using activator 1.3.10 and no `src_managed` nor `classes_managed` directories are created when compiling the project.

The project runs fine when I only use activator to compile and run it. But the absence of this directory causes trouble with my IntelliJ Idea as it is looking for reverse routing classes in "src_managed".

Here are the steps to demonstrate this problem on a Linux machine :

Open a terminal :

```
$ activator new my-first-app play-scala
$ cd my-first-app
$ activator
```

Then in my-first-app acivator invite, you can chek that source-managed is correctly configured :

```
my-first-app> source-managed
```

And finally compile and run it :

```
my-first-app> compile
my-first-app> run
```

At this point, `my-first-app/scala-2.11/src_managed` and `my-first-app/scala-2.11/classes_managed` should exist... but they don't...

Playframework documentation states that `src_managed` and  `classes_managed` directories should exist :
https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/Anatomy#The-target/-directory

Has anyone encountered this issue ? If so, how did you resolve it ?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Antonin, those `src_managed` and `classes_managed` directories won't necessarily get created if Play doesn't need them (in a nutshell it depends on what you are doing in your app).

If you have IDE errors to do with routing then try putting `target/scala-2.11/routes/main` on the build path in IntelliJ.

If you have errors to do with the twirl templates then also add `target/scala-2.11/twirl/main`.

You will need to do a clean compile and possibly refresh the application in the IDE to make the issues disappear (at least with Eclipse this is my experience anyway).

Comment: Thanks Nio this is indeed the fix I use.Meaning that depending on the native feature of play I use, I have to first build the project using sbt (and not "make" from intelliJ), and then add manually the generated source directories. This is not done automaticaly during sbt project import